# How can I integrate the Apache Solr Search with my Drupal 7 Site?

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7, database-performance

Can anyone Give me the Good tutorial links which will be helpful to me so I can check that How to Integrate the Solr Search with my Drupal Site to get good performance.

What are the modules available for Drupal 7.x Version of Apache Solr Search.
Which version of Solr will support the Drupal 7.x.
What are the Configuration should required in Apache Solr / Drupal 7.x to Search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two modules that support Solr with Drupal that are widely used:

- [Search API Solr](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr)
- [ApacheSolr search](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr)

Both have their various configuration 'quirks', I'd say you'd need to try both to see how they fit in with your site, to see which suits you best.

Make sure you have **Java 5** or higher installed already on your server.

- [Tutorial on setting up site with Search API for Solr](http://zugec.com/73-how-setup-search-api-apache-solr)
- [Tutorial on setting up site with ApacheSolr](http://nickveenhof.be/blog/screencast-1-installing-apache-solr-module-and-server-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

Look at and use Search API - Apache Solr module will not be the way forward for the future of Drupal.

The two maintainers of Search API and Apache Solr have meet in person and have determined a way forward for advanced searches with Drupal and they both have agreed that Search API is it.